# Дружественный шаблонный класс

Tags: c++

Почему `gcc` выдаёт ошибку?

> [Error] specialization of 'template class A' must appear at namespace scope

```
template<class T1, class T2>
class A
{
    template<class T3>
    friend class A<T1, T3>;
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В С++ нет возможности использования частичной специализации для того, чтобы "очертить" только какое-то подмножество специализаций шаблона в качестве друзей.

> **14.5.4 Friends**
>
> **8** Friend declarations shall not declare partial specializations. [ Example:

```
  template<class T> class A { };
  class X {
    template<class T> friend class A<T*>; // error
  };
```

> —end example ]

То есть другом может быть либо шаблон (со всеми его специализациями), либо конкретная специализация (т.е *полная* специализация) шаблона.

Comment: Ну вот, я это чувствовал, что специализации не будет :) Спасибо за указание на стандарт.

Comment: это печально; но я же могу указать все параметры, а те, которые должны остаться неизменными просто сравнить с помощью `std::is_same`?

Answer (score 2):

Уберите `<T2>`:

```
template<class T>
class A
{
    template<class T2>
    friend class A;
};
```

Update:

ну... опять же -

```
template<class T1, class T3>
friend class A;
```

Впрочем, не очень уверен, что сработает именно специализация.

Comment: а если у меня несколько параметров и я хочу добавить конкретно эту специализацию в друзья?

Comment: изменил вопрос.

Comment: Дописал в ответ.

Comment: Так у вас же 2 аргумента, а мне нужно, чтобы какое-то количество сохранилось(`T1`), а другие поменялись(`T2` -> `T3`)

Comment: Т.е. нужно специализацию использовать